# Get value of object(stdClass) not with looping

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have some array object value like this :

```
object(stdClass)#32 (1) { 
    ["0"]=> object(stdClass)#33 (2) { 
                ["plan_type"]=> string(5) "offer" 
                ["plan_id"]=> string(4) "7395"
            } 
}
```

I want to get the value of `plan_type` from that object. How could I do that without looping ?

Comment: try cast object to array and use `array_column` to get values for that specific key plan_type

Comment: OuterObject->NestedObject->NestedObjectProperty?

Comment: @Beamer180 I got `Undefined property: stdClass::$plan_type` with that.

Comment: @Akintunde maybe you can give me some example please ?

Comment: just use like this $object[0]->plan_type;